# OOM when reading data from mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I am getting an OOM error when trying to read a large result set using MyBatis.
MyBatis version 3.5
I want to iterate over the cursor instead of loading the entire query result.
Does anyone have a working example of returning a cursor from mybatis select instead of entire result.

```
[java] SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
[java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[java] AsyncLogger error handling event seq=0, value='null':
[java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[java] 06 Sep 2020 05:34:34,682 [ERROR]  (http-nio-0.0.0.0-8243-ClientPoller-1) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint:
[java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[java]  at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1043) ~[?:?]
[java]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

ReaderDao.xml

```
<select id="downloadelements" resultMap="elementMap">
    select *
    from sample_table
    where element_timestamp between #{startTime} and #{endTime}
    and status=#{status}
</select>
```

ReaderDao.java

```
public interface ReaderDao {
Cursor<Element> downloadElements(final @NotNull @Param("startTime") ZonedDateTime startTime,
                                                final @NotNull @Param("endTime") ZonedDateTime endTime,
                                                final @NotNull @Param("status") String status);
}
```

Database: Aurora PostgreSQL

```
Cursor<Element> elementList = downloadElements(start, end, status);
Iterator<Element> elementIterator = elementList.iterator();
while (elementIterator.hasNext()) {
    Element element = ElementIterator.next();
    log.info(element.toString());
}
```

```xml
<resultMap id="elementMap" type="Element">
    <constructor>
        <arg javaType="String" column="status"/>
        <arg javaType="java.time.ZonedDateTime" column="start_time"/>
        <arg javaType="java.util.Optional" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"  column="end_time"/>
    </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Show the code which is causing the high memory consumption, otherwise we have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: I have added the code that is not working.
I am not sure how to return a cursor from a select statement. I could not find much information in the documentation.
The goal is to not read the entire data from the db in one go as it is bound to cause a OOM error.

Comment: Please add 1) the result map `elementMap`, 2) the code processing `Cursor`, 3) database version and 4) driver version.

Comment: I have added the details. I am not sure what the driver version is.

Comment: pgjdbc does not seem to support streaming result set at the moment. There is an open [PR](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1735) for the enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [PostgreSQL driver does not support streaming results](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1735) (as pointed out by @ave) you most likely want to implement result pagination. This is usually done either by using `ORDER BY element_timestamp LIMIT <n> OFFSET <k>` or by using [keyset pagination](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/keyset-pagination/). Either of these methods will load smaller batches of results into memory hopefully avoiding OOME by allowing GC to free each batch separately.

However it should be noted that sometimes increasing the available heap memory is the easiest solution. RAM is usually cheaper than programmers time so perhaps you should start by estimating how many records are you trying to process and how much memory is needed.

Comment: Thanks I will try keyset pagination.